# Create trigger that Find, Parse and Insert to another table After inserting on table

Tags: mysql, trigger

I want to create a trigger that will insert to another table after inserting on my table.

Scenario:
I will insert on my inbox table.
Then, on my inbox table there is a field named Msg.
Next, I want to parse the Msg before inserting it. 
The data is: `su:11:2016-07-18:2:125~1, 124~100`

```
    CREATE TRIGGER account_insert AFTER INSERT ON inbox FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT 
    SPLIT_STR(Msg, ':', '1') AS u,
    SPLIT_STR(Msg, ':', '2') AS o,
    SPLIT_STR(Msg, ':', '3') AS dt,
    SPLIT_STR(Msg, ':', '4') AS t
FROM inbox ORDER BY Datestamp DESC

INSERT ON account (trx_id, user_id, outlet_id, date_captured) VALUES(t, u, o, dt)

END;
```

So the output must be like this:

```
trx_id = 2
user_id = su
outlet_id =11
date_captured = 2016-07-18
```

I cannot run this on MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `SPLIT_STR()`.  But a couple uses of `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` will do the trick.